# Not able to install the gdal module of python

Tags: python, installation, terminal, module, gdal

pip installed both gdal and osgeo modules, yet im getting an issue as shown.
[gdal terminal installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfDPA.png)
[osgeo terminal installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtNxV.png)

How do I go past this?
Note - Had recently installed anaconda on my system since, I am having trouble with installation of certain modules.

First off tried pip installing both to my main folder and ran the code but it showed osgeo/gdal module missing.
After that made a new env and now the errors are shown above.

Comment: Please post the error messages a text blocks, not as screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the GDAL libraries:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

Second, install the same version from PIP to match your installation. You can check the version by typing `gdalinfo --version` in your terminal. For example, if you get 3.7.1, you need to run `pip install GDAL==3.7.1`.